# Format-Size-Larger/Smaller shortcut disabled in M10? [fixed in v.10.1]

Tags: front-end, bugs, formatting, windows

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 or earlier and persisting through 10.0.1 and 10.0.2. Fixed in 10.1**

---

It seems that the keyboard shortcuts for enlarging/reducing the font size (ALT+= / ALT+-) don't work anymore in M10 as it did in M9.
If I select the text (or code) **inside** a cell they work.
But if I select **a cell or more cells** they don't do anything anymore.
The only way to change the font size of some cells is now to go through the *Format-Size* menu.

With M9 I used these shortcuts very often to gradually adjust the font size of one or more cells.

Maybe there is some setting in the Option Inspector that I must change?
(I'm on windows 8.1 64bit)

Comment: I can confirm this problem, but not in exactly the same way.  The keys seems to have no effect on most Cells but on Text Cells they change the font size *only* between 10pt and 14pt, so the keys are active in some way yet ineffective as well.  I am running Windows 7.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I should mention that with graphics cells, even in Linux the cell is not enlarged. Only the `Out[..]` and the margin around the graphics gets bigger. It works in every cell that contains text: like message cells, output cells, Print cells etc.

Comment: I can confirm this problem on **Windows 8.1**

Comment: I am adding the bugs tag because this doesn't work the same way across platforms, therefore this presumably is not an intentional change.

Comment: Any update on whether it is fixed? If so, would you please edit the header (see http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching)?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Problem solved with v. 10.1

Answer (score 2):

In Linux this still works:

[image]

and even in the [official documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html) the shortcuts are still listed under *Format Menu*.

This problem seems to be local to your machine.

Comment: works ok on Mac also.

Comment: Any Windows user?

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed v10.0.1 and with disappoint I see that this bug (Windows 8.1) hasn't been solved.
I even tried unisntalling v9 considering that the 2 version share the same $UserBaseDirectory and that there could be some conflict. But that didn't help.

It drives me crazy because the menu command (Format-Size-Larger/Smaller) works as expected, but the corresponding keyboard shortcuts don't.

Maybe some expert can give me some hint on how to modify the MenuSetup.tr file to have working shortcuts doing this menu functions?
The code lines in the default MenuSetup.tr file are:

```
....
 Menu["Si&ze", 
         {
            MenuItem["&Larger", FontSize->Larger, MenuKey["=", Modifiers->{"Command"}]],
            MenuItem["&Smaller", FontSize->Smaller, MenuKey["-", Modifiers->{"Command"}]],
            Delimiter,
....
```